# How can I achieve this double join in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, sqlite, inner-join

I have this query, which joins the names of events which are stored in a cache table.

```
SELECT OccurrenceCache.occurrence_date, CalendarItem.summary FROM OccurrenceCache
    INNER JOIN CalendarItem ON CalendarItem.ROWID = OccurrenceCache.event_id
    WHERE OccurrenceCache.occurrence_date >= (strftime('%s', 'now', 'localtime', 'start of day') - strftime('%s', '2001-01-01', 'start of day')) AND OccurrenceCache.occurrence_end_date <= (strftime('%s', 'now', 'localtime', 'start of day') - strftime('%s', '2001-01-01', 'start of day') + 24 * 60 * 60);
```

Now I want to include location data of the events too, which are stored in a table named *Location*. The location entries are referenced by CalendarItem.location_id (0 means that no location is specified). I tried it with another JOIN-statement, but it does not work:

```
SELECT OccurrenceCache.occurrence_date, CalendarItem.summary, Location.title FROM OccurrenceCache
    INNER JOIN CalendarItem ON CalendarItem.ROWID = OccurrenceCache.event_id
    INNER JOIN Location ON Location.ROWID = CalendarItem.location_id
    WHERE OccurrenceCache.occurrence_date >= (strftime('%s', 'now', 'localtime', 'start of day') - strftime('%s', '2001-01-01', 'start of day')) AND OccurrenceCache.occurrence_end_date <= (strftime('%s', 'now', 'localtime', 'start of day') - strftime('%s', '2001-01-01', 'start of day') + 24 * 60 * 60);
```

It returns 0 results.

Comment: Hard to say without sample data but I'm guessing: does every row in OccurenceCache have a matching entry in CalendarItem _and_ Location? If not, use "LEFT JOIN"s instead of "INNER JOIN"s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case that all your entries in the `Location` table don't match the `calenderitem` table, using `LEFT JOIN` instead will be the solution.

```
SELECT OccurrenceCache.occurrence_date, CalendarItem.summary, Location.title FROM OccurrenceCache
    INNER JOIN CalendarItem ON CalendarItem.ROWID = OccurrenceCache.event_id
    LEFT JOIN Location ON Location.ROWID = CalendarItem.location_id
    WHERE OccurrenceCache.occurrence_date >= (strftime('%s', 'now', 'localtime', 'start of day') - strftime('%s', '2001-01-01', 'start of day')) AND OccurrenceCache.occurrence_end_date <= (strftime('%s', 'now', 'localtime', 'start of day') - strftime('%s', '2001-01-01', 'start of day') + 24 * 60 * 60);
```

[Using Outer Joins in SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)